# How to make a custom eslint rule to check if a method is called before another?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have a class, Is it possible to have a eslint rule to check if b() is called before developer calls a()?

```
class A {
  a(){return this}
  b(){return this}
}
const c= new A();
c.a() // warning: b() has to be called before a()
c.b().a() // no eslint warning
```

Comment: if only chaining is possible you could verify it with typescript. but otherwise you cant, since there is no static way to ever know if a was called before

Comment: @Lux could you elaborate more on how to verify it with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to allow the chain you can enforce this by typescript.

Basically with typescript you can type it like this:

```
interface FullA {
    a(): FullA;
    b(): FullA;
}
interface ABeforeB {
    b(): FullA;
}
```

and just type you class as `ABeforeA` instead of `FullA`.

However if you want to allow this:

```
c.b();
c.a();
```

There is *no way* to check this at compile time. The only way to check if `a()` is called before `b()` is to *execute the programm*.

A short example why this is the case: Assume this program:

```
const c = new A();
if(Math.random() > .5) {
  c.b();
}
c.a();
```

In this case in 50% of the cases you will have in error, in 50% of the cases it will work fine. And the `if` clause could be arbitrary complex.

Answer (score -2):

A module is a npm bundle that typically fares rules. Some modules additionally send out at least one named arrangements. Ensure the bundle has been introduced to a catalog where ESLint can require it.